# Is it possible to set the path using an install shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I plan to create a program using shell and is it possible to edit the user's path and alias? Or is it normal etiquette to post an instruction that says something like:

1. "paste this in your path in .bash_profile"
2. "paste this in your alias in .bash_profile"

like the one shown here: https://github.com/icefox/git-achievements/blob/gh-pages/README

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's poor etiquette to do either. Create a shell script that invokes your application using `exec`, and put that in `$PREFIX/bin` or `$PREFIX/sbin`.

Comment: can you please point me to an example on how to do this? and the $PREFIX/bin should be in my shell script?

Comment: @ignacio I agree that it is preferable to set env variables in the script, then exec the app BUT @corroded is asking also about aliases, and we have to assume that his app is NOT installed in the exiting path or he would not have to do anything.

Comment: @nhed: `$PREFIX` is a build-time variable, not a runtime variable.

Comment: so how do i go about with the $PREFIX guys?

Comment: Put the shell script in `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.

Comment: @Ignacio I know that `$PREFIX` is from build time, but you are asking @corroded to install SOMETHING in a standard location, which, if I read the question right, he is trying to avoid (I am guessing he wants all files from his app in `/opt/myapp` or somesuch)