# How to add your application path to the user's shell path?

Tags: shell, path, bash

Is there a way to add your application path to a user's .bash_profile path variable using shell script? Also, what if the user was using a different shell like zsh etc? Is it possible to "universally" add your application path to the user's shell PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different shells have different syntaxes so there's no real "standard" way.

There are a couple of things you can do.

1. Install your application confirming to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) so that the default paths work. This means that your executables will be (alteast symlinked) in /usr/bin etc.
2. At the end of your installation routine, spit out a few shells snippets that the user can stick into their shell initialisation scripts so that they can use your application. You can also take this a level further and test the users SHELL variable and insert the appropriate snippet into the correct initialisation file. This might be unwise though. I don't like programs modifying my personal init files. You can support the `csh` "family" and the `bash` "family". That should cover *most* of the cases. People who use more obscure shells will most probably be knowledgeable enough to port the PATH settings anyway.

Comment: "At the end of your installation routine, spit out a few shells snippets that the user can stick into their shell initialisation scripts so that they can use your application." -- i was given the impression in my last post that this was unwise. why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555935/is-it-possible-to-set-the-path-using-an-install-shell-script

Comment: Because it's poor form and you're shifting the job of maintaining the package to the user. The first approach is much more desirable.

Comment: but wasnt that what you suggested? to tell a user to stick it in their shell init scripts?

Comment: Yup. Only if for some reason, you cannot do the former (e.g. installation without administrative privileges).

Comment: i see so it's some sort of fallback then?

Comment: I'd consider it a last resort yes.

Comment: The suggestion of installing wherever you want but just dropping in a shell script in the standard locations that launch your application is an excellent idea.